# How can I make sure ffmpeg is found with videohash?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, path, digital-ocean

I have been trying to deploy an app on Digital Ocean; I have installed the necessary packages but I keep getting an error from the videohash library: `videohash.exceptions.FFmpegNotFound` I have tried adding the ffmpeg package directory to `PATH` by running:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/workspace/web/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffmpeg"
```

I also tried adding it as an environment variable at app and component level and adding the export command to `./bashrc` but nothing I do seems to work. Is there another way I could try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you setting a variable in ipython console

```
import os, os.environ['PATH']+=':/workspace/web/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffmpeg'
```

`in Tools → Preference → iPython console → Startup → Lines.`

I suppose a similar solution can be applied if Python console is being used instead of iPython console.

You can also check [here](https://ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. I imagine that the PATH variable probably resets as you exit the python interpreter.